# addSubview does not work

Tags: iphone, addsubview

I will add a label to an Image with addSubview but this does not work.

here the code:

```
.h
    UIImageView *bgimage;
    IBOutet UILabel *loadingLabel;


.m
    loadingLabel.text =@"......";
    bgimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    bgimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wait.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:bgimage];
    [bgimage addSubview:loadingLabel];
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

"Tisch wird reserviert..." is the loadinglabel and is label shoud be in the UiImage

[image: Screenshot 2]

This is the "Layout" with the code from 2nd answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code as...

.h

```
IBOutet UIImageView *bgimage;
UILabel *loadingLabel;
```

.m

```
bgimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wait.png"];
loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
loadingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
loadingLabel.text = @"testing";
[bgimage addSubview:loadingLabel];
```

It will work.

Comment: This means that i need a UIImageView on my xib file? is this right? at the moment I have no Uiimageview on my xib file only the label

Comment: your UILabel is added on xib file. Instead add UIImageView on xib and add the UILabel on that.

Comment: Hello, I have testet this and I locks very ugly not I aspacted is there now other way to add the label on the uiimageview?

Comment: Actually I dont know what is in your mind :-). Can you share any screenshot? to load an UILabel into an UIImageView, you just need to add the UILabel into the UIImageView. [your_imageView addSubview:your_label]

Comment: ok I added a screenshot to my question. This is the "layout" with my code I added in the question but de label is not in the UiImage but i have [bgimage addSubview:loadinglabel];

Comment: Have you removed the UILabel from xib? Create that UILabel as I stated above.

Comment: With your code It looks like very confuse I added a screenshot in question

Comment: You have to set the UILabel background as clearColor and also have to set the UILabel frame position according to your desire. Please check this project, https://github.com/MasudShuvo/TestUILabelOnUIImageView

Comment: If you do not want my suggestion and want to strict to your code(You submitted in the question), What you need to do is, just modify the .m code as follow, loadingLabel.text =@".......";
    bgimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    bgimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wait.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:bgimage];
    [loadingLabel removeFromSuperview];
    loadingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [bgimage addSubview:loadingLabel];

Answer (score 2):

You cant add a subview to a uiimageview, since drawRect: will never be called. 
source:
"The "UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call the drawRect: method of a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class." from the apple docs:https://www.google.de/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=90e2434f04e1ee9b&q=uiimageview+class+reference&safe=off

Solution:
As suggested, use a uiview to contain both the label and the imageview, and then bring the label to the top using -bringSubviewtoFront: of UIView. You can also use a UIViews backgroundimage to show your image and then have a label as a subclass in that view. Depends on the Situation you are in, i guess.

EDIT: YOU SHOULD READ THIS:
I misread the question, and it appears that you can add subviews to UIImageView, just like Zev pointed out in his comment. Right now im guessing that -bringSubviewToFront did the trick for you, and that the rest of my answer, while not really harmful, was unnecessary. Im sorry.

Comment: @Nils - actually my source is way off and i missed our point a little bit. but im glad this solution also works in your case. Ill look into it and correct my answer with the right sources, when i find them.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that didn’t sound right. I have added subviews to `UIImageView`s plenty of times. `-drawRect:` is different from `-layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg - actually, im talking about subclassing uiImageView in my anwer. i didnt get that Nils used addSubview when i read it. entirely my mistake...

Comment: Ok thanks but I did not get this :( How I get the label on the UIImage I posted a screenshot and there is the label not in the UIImage (it is above the UIImage)